# Wordpress get_terms & wp_query shows wrong results

Tags: php, wordpress, nested-loops, custom-taxonomy

I do have subpage where I want to present & filter job postings for my clients company.

The filtering is based on two taxonomies:

- job-category (examples: logistics, hr, marketing etc); filtering done by using select field called categoryfilter
- job-country (examples: germany, France etc); filtering done by using select field called taxonomyfilter

**What works:**

- filtering by countries
- filtering by categories
- filtering by both taxonomies

**What doesn't work:**

- while filtering ONLY by countries the expected behaviour is to show only taxonomies and its posts that belong to specific country;
- if a taxonomy job-country element do not have any post belonging, it should not be presented

In the current version of my code when I filter the results by country it shows the results in such a manner:

```
JOB CATEGORY 1
post
post

JOB CATEGORY 2
Sorry, no openings found

JOB CATEGORY 3
post
post
post
```

So simply I want to get rid of the entire JOB CATEGORY 2 (and not showing info about lack of openings). I do have an impression that the issue with my code is related to the part with taxquery if statements. Yet I am unable to diagonze whats wrong there :/

CODE:

```
function multiple_filter_function()
{

  $list_custom_taxonomy = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
    'name' => $_POST['categoryfilter'],
    'hide_empty' => true
  ));

  foreach ($list_custom_taxonomy as $custom_single_term) {

    echo '<h2 class="category-title">' . $custom_single_term->name . '</h2>';

    $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
      'order'  => $_POST['date'], // ASC or DESC
      'post_type' => 'career',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    /* taxquery if statements */
    if (isset($_POST['categoryfilter']) && isset($_POST['taxonomyfilter'])) {
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',

        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'job-country',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $_POST['taxonomyfilter']
        ),
      );
    } elseif (!isset($_POST['categoryfilter']) && isset($_POST['taxonomyfilter'])) {
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $custom_single_term->name,
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'job-country',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $_POST['taxonomyfilter']
        )
      );
    } elseif (isset($_POST['categoryfilter']) && !isset($_POST['taxonomyfilter'])) {
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
        )
      );
    }
    /* END of taxquery if statements */

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
      echo $query->post->post_title;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
      echo '<p class="text-center">Sorry, no openings found</p>';
    endif;
  }

  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter_2', 'multiple_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter_2', 'multiple_filter_function');
```

Comment: _"I do have an impression that the issue with my code is related to the part with taxquery if statements."_ - those come only _after_ you have already output `echo '<h2 class="category-title">' . $custom_single_term->name . '</h2>';` at the beginning of your loop over the taxonomy terms. The simplest solution would be that you move that output into the `if ($query->have_posts())` block, and remove the else block that currently shows the "Sorry, no openings found" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by CBroe in the comments. IMO, its the most viable solution.

```
function multiple_filter_function()
{

  $list_custom_taxonomy = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
    'name' => $_POST['categoryfilter'],
    'hide_empty' => true
  ));

  foreach ($list_custom_taxonomy as $custom_single_term) {

    $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
      'order'  => $_POST['date'], // ASC or DESC
      'post_type' => 'career',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    /* taxquery if statements */
    if (isset($_POST['categoryfilter']) && isset($_POST['taxonomyfilter'])) {
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',

        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'job-country',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $_POST['taxonomyfilter']
        ),
      );
    } elseif (!isset($_POST['categoryfilter']) && isset($_POST['taxonomyfilter'])) {
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $custom_single_term->name,
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'job-country',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $_POST['taxonomyfilter']
        )
      );
    } elseif (isset($_POST['categoryfilter']) && !isset($_POST['taxonomyfilter'])) {
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
        )
      );
    }
    /* END of taxquery if statements */

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) : 
      echo '<h2 class="category-title">' . $custom_single_term->name . '</h2>';
      while ($query->have_posts()) : 
         $query->the_post();
         echo $query->post->post_title;
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
  }

  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter_2', 'multiple_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter_2', 'multiple_filter_function');
```